# SMTP Error "check for new mail first"

Tags: email, smtp

I need to send e mail from a asp.net web site. The mail server is not in same network with the web server (it's in different location). Sometime it sends the mail without any error, but sometimes it does not work and gives an error saying,

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: address@domain.com must
>   check for new mail first

Any idea whats causing this issue?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP_before_SMTP

Comment: @symcbean Can I change 'POP_before_SMTP' option in mail server?

Comment: probably. Maybe if you said what the mailserver was people might be able to give more specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the target host has it set up where a user mailbox doesn't get created until a/that given user has checked for new mail; at which time the system will create the respective mailbox files.

Chances are this is a host that uses virtual mailboxes driven off of a database;

There's a near-identical thread on [stackoverflow that gives a similar consensus.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380792/error-when-sending-emails-from-net-web-site)